# Deutsche Redewendung für „Sit around the campfire and sing Kumbaya“

Tags: phrase, expression

Ich habe nach einem Äquivalent auf Deutsch gesucht, konnte aber keines finden. Das einzige, das mir einfällt ist *Abwarten und Tee trinken*, aber ich glaube nicht, dass dies den Sarkasmus und die implizierte Blauäugigkeit der Zielperson enthält. Auch der Sinn von unerwünschten Geselligkeit mit seinen Feinden sollte dabei sein.

Hier sind einige Links, die die Bedeutung auf Englisch erklären:

- [urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sing%20Kumbaya)
- [answers.yahoo.com](https://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20131004103235AAGAL5a)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Spontan würde ich

> einen auf [Friede-Freude-Eierkuchen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friede,_Freude,_Eierkuchen) machen

dazu sagen.

Die Sequenz *[einen auf ... machen](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~einen%20auf%20...%20machen&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou)* bedeutet umgangssprachlich *so tun, als ob*, *etwas vorspielen*, *Friede, Freude, Eierkuchen* ist eine scheinbare Harmonie, die unterschwellige Probleme verdrängt.

Comment: Eine Alternative wäre auch _einen auf eitel Sonnenschein machen_.

Answer (score 2):

Vielleicht "**Wir fassen uns an den Händen und haben uns alle lieb**" oder "... **und singen Aba Heidschi Bumbeidschi**" (es muss dann schon ein etwas dämlich-naiver Liedtitel sein; "*Eiapopeia*" wäre auch nicht schlecht, aber um es zu erkennen, würde man wohl den ganzen Titel nennen müssen, und der ist "Eiapopeia, was raschelt im Stroh", das wäre zu lang und umständlich und würde die Pointe abschwächen).

Den Satz aus Urbandictionary.com

*At the risk of sounding too kumbaya, I felt as if I had finally come home.*

würde ich so übersetzen:

*Für manche kommt das jetzt vielleicht etwas **friede-freude-eierkuchenmäßig** / **eiapopeiamäßig** (= gefühlsduselig) rüber, aber ich hab' mich da endlich mal wirklich daheim gefühlt.*

Answer (score 1):

Wie ich aus [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumbaya) gelernt habe, ist *Kumbaya* is ein Spiritual aus den 1920-er Jahren mit einfachem Text (im Wesentlichen "Kumbaya, my Lord, kumbaya"), in dem Gott gebeten wird, zu Hilfe zu kommen.

Im Laufe der Zeit ist es aber Bestandteil des sarkastischen Ausdrucks in "Sit around the campfire and sing Kumbaya" geworden. Dazu mag auch der für viele Hörer schlicht und naiv klingende Text beigetragen haben. [Zitat](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/kumbaya/):

> In the late 1980–90s, however, the concept of kumbaya started being met with cynicism. Thanks to its associations with childish sing-alongs, kumbaya started signaling naive idealism and a sort of precious, touchy-feely, hand-holding spirit of rosy-eyed unity. The derisive term especially took off in political rhetoric. As then-Congressman Rick Santorum mocked a national proposal to pay students for service in 1994: “Someone’s going to pick up trash in a park and sing ‘Kumbaya‘ around a campfire, and you’re going to give them 90 percent of the benefits of the GI Bill!” In 2015, as another example, President Barack Obama remarked of the Israeli-Palestinian peace process: “So this can’t be reduced to a matter of, somehow, let’s all hold hands and sing ‘Kumbaya.’”

In Stephies Antwort findet sich ein hervorragender Übersetzungsvorschlag. Eine andere Variante ist

**Am Esstisch sitzen und "Piep, piep, piep! Wir ha’m uns alle lieb" sagen.**

Der Kumbaya-Spruch scheint allerdings, wie obiges Zitat zeigt, auch zu einem politischen Kampfbegriff geworden zu sein. Weiteres [Zitat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumbaya):

> Beginning in the 1990s and increasing in the following decades, references to "Kumbaya" or "singing Kumbaya" entered idiomatic usage in the politics of the United States, often to suggest that someone other than the speaker is too conciliatory or eager to compromise. Professor Richard Vatz of Towson University has characterized these references to the song as sarcastic criticism of consensus "that allegedly does not examine the issues or is revelatory of cockeyed optimism."

Im politischen Kontext wäre also

**Beschwichtigungspolitik machen**

eine angemessene Übersetzung, auch wenn sie nicht den Sarkasmus des englischen Orignals wiedergibt.

**Update:**

Bei "Piep, piep, piep, ..." handelt es sich um ein althergebrachtes Tischritual beim Essen mit Kindern. Man reicht sich die Hände und sagt dann den Spruch auf. Vgl. die Antwort von Ralf Joerres sowie [hier](https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idForum=33&idThread=1006701&lp=itde&lang=de) und [hier](https://www.pinterest.de/pin/234327986842972252/). Auch im politischen Umfeld wird der Spruch gelegentlich benutzt. [Beispiel aus der Presse](https://www.lr-online.de/nachrichten/piep_-piep_-piep_-wir-haben-uns-alle-lieb-35842946.html):

> **Piep, piep, piep, wir haben uns alle lieb**

> Die Grünen-Führung wollte Konflikte auf dem Parteitag in Hamburg vermeiden. Das ist ihr gelungen. Aber Kontroversen wurden eher verdeckt als ausgetragen.

> ...

> Einige Delegierte sind davon wenig angetan. "Piep, piep, piep, wir haben uns alle lieb", spottet Jörg Rupp vom Kreisverband Karlsruhe. Der neue Antrag wende sich "gegen den Diskurs, den wir brauchen", schimpft der bayerische Landesvorsitzende Dieter Janecek. Doch der Parteitag ist auf Harmonie gepolt. Das Papier erhält eine breite Mehrheit.

Comment: Ich habe deinen Antwort vor einigen Tagen gelesen.. Ja das habe ich noch nicht gehört "Piep, piep, piep! Wir ha’m uns alle lieb" aber es klingt vernünftig. Das, was du zitiert hast fasst es meistens zusammen aber ich glaube, dass es noch ein kleine etwas gibt - Schwarze Sklaven und ihr Halter gemeinsam um das Lagerfeuer gesessen und Kumbaya gesungen und so es heißt manchmal teilweise auch, mit deinem Feind oder unliebsamem Arbeitgeber "Piep, piep, piep! Wir ha’m uns alle lieb" sagen bzw. singen.

Comment: @cardamom Ich habe dazu ein Update gemacht.

Answer (score -3):

Vielleicht funktioniert "Gute Mine zum bösen Spiel". "Eine gute Mine zum bösen Spiel machen" bedeutet, dass man einen unerwünschten Umstand hinnimmt und sich seinen Ärger nicht anmerken lässt. Leider enthält das (wie Friede-Freude-Eierkuchen auch) keine implizierte Blauäugigkeit.